# MSM MF110/MF627/MF636 and Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, 3g, mobile-broadband

I have a 3g modem, from Orange. My `lsusb` output:

`Bus 003 Device 004: ID 19d2:0031 ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM MF110/MF627/MF636`

So, the problem is that this modem is not always detected. For example when I turn on my notebook, I wait ~ 40 seconds and sometimes the connection appears in the connections menu, but sometimes not. Can anyone explain me what is the problem and how to fix it ?

Using Ubuntu 13.04 64

PS: Sorry for my english, I am from Romania.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, after a lot of reading and searching on the other forums, I fixed it with `sudo eject /dev/sr1`
 and after this, I wait <=30 seconds and my device is found. I as understood, my modem was mounter as usb-storage, and I all have to is to eject it.

Sorry for my english, I hope somebody will find this usefull!

Answer (score 0):

The same started happening to me yesterday, and it seems that a restart of the modem-manager solves the problem.

Try to run in a terminal window the following:

```
sudo killall -9 modem-manager
```

I found it on the following site:
http://bugs.rosalinux.ru/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=1792

For me the modem-manager was automatically restarted.

You can run

```
tail -f less /var/log/syslog
```

from a separate terminal window to see what happens.